How can the macros of the virtual scene be executed from the terminal?
I'm doing some tests with the virtual scene of the android emulator, the thing is that I have modified the file Toren1BD.posters and put a qr code in the position 0 0 of the virtual scene, but when you start the camera does not come out in the 0 0.
I have seen that you can run some macros that move the position in the virtual scene, there is one that leads to the position 0 0 and works fine.
I would like to know if you can run this macro from the terminal.
I have not found any information is this possible?

You can use automation command of emulator console.
Information is present here:
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-console

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
